# If a microprocessor and bus have different bit systems, is the microprocessor system bus cycle (continued)

Tags: cpu, hardware, execution, microprocessors, bus

Full Question: **If a microprocessor and bus have different bit systems, is the microprocessor system bus cycle the amount of time it takes to get the microprocessor's amount of bits, or the system bus's?**

Example:
If the microprocessor has a 64-bit system and the system bus has a 32-bit system, would the microprocessor's system bus cycle be the amount of time to receive 64 bits or 32 bits?

Comment: My concern is that it would take 2 cycles for the microprocessor to receive 64 bits of information, rather than 1. Sorry if this is a newbie question, but I'm just getting into hardware execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no general answer to your question.
Every context gives its meaning to the words used.

As stated "microprocessor system bus cycle" is ambiguous: it could mean *the cycle of the system bus of the microprocessor* or *the cycle of the microprocessor system bus (interface)*.
Using your example, the former delivers 32 bits in a cycle, the latter 64.

I'm inclined toward the first interpretation.
Unless you have a datasheet or some fact that could prove or disprove one the interpretation, you can pick the one you like the most (evidently it doesn't matter in the context).

Comment: I guess to give more context I'm trying to find the maximum data transfer rate between the bus and processor. In the context, the processor's system bus cycle takes 8 input clock cycles from the bus. I know how to find it except I don't know whether each cycle is for 32 bits or 64

Comment: @JonDoe The answer can be found only in your source reference. If that number 8 is the number of system bus cycles, then I'd say they are 32-bit transfers.